# How to set a whole matrix with specific value in OpenCV like Matlab

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I want to do in OpenCV something like "A(A == val) = 0" that works in Matlab. I implemented some code but these are too slow (I use it many times)

I tried to do something like:

```
MatIterator_<T> it;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  tmp = in.row(i);
  end = tmp.end<T>();
  for (it = tmp.begin<T>(); it != end; ++it)
     if (*it == val) *it = 0;
}
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  *ptr = in.ptr<T>(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
     if (*ptr == val) *ptr = 0;
     ptr++;
  }
}
```

I hope some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sets all elements of target that are 42 to the new value, 12:

```
cv::Mat mask = target == 42;
target.setTo(12, mask);
```

Comment: You can just do: target.setTo(12, target == 42);

Comment: You can, but I wanted to make it clear what the type of `target == 42` is (a Mat), because otherwise someone skim-reading might think it's a lambda.

Comment: I have not measured it, but I expect it to be much slower. I am yet to find an OpenCV function that _isn't_ surprisingly, comically slow for some reason.

Comment: (I therefore posted it mostly in a fit of sheer optimism that maybe they got this one simple thing right. Maybe.)